# Pulling data in JSON file through a-frame html

Tags: jquery, json, aframe

I am trying to make a 360 view using a-frame framework. There will be several panels(planes) in the scene. The data from an external JSON file will be displayed on those panels.

Here is some of the data from the external JSON file:

```
  "data": [
  {
        "id": 1,
        "state_id": 1,
        "name": "Titi Tinggi",
        "code_name": "N1",
        "type": "DUN",
        "hot_seat": true,
        "election_year": 2013,
        "registered_voters": 9159,
        "spoilt": 0,
        "turnout": 7332,
        "turnout_percent": 80,
        "majority": 1486,
        "majority_percent": 20,
        "race_malay": 6734,
        "race_chinese": 2128,
        "race_india": 258,
        "race_bumi": null,
        "race_nonbumi": null,
        "race_others": 54,
        "state": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Perlis",
            "code": "PER"
```

I tried using jquery to fetch the data. It didnt show any errors but the 360 image is somewhat 'blocking' the data.

```
     AFRAME.registerComponent ('jsonreader',
  {
    init: function()
    {
      $.getJSON('seat_perlis.json', function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $('#test').text(data.data[0].name);

       });
    }
  });
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution. Unfortunately, failed miserably.

Comment: We would need a [mcve] and perhaps look in the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$('#test').text(json)` you are creating HTML. From the FAQ, [A-Frame cannot render raw HTML content](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-display-lt-iframe-gt-s-or-render-html-in-a-frame). You must instead use something like the [`<a-text/>` component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/primitives/a-text.html) to generate a WebGL-compatible version.

```
var el = document.createElement('a-text');
el.setAttribute('value', data.data[0].name);
sceneEl.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: I'll try to do it using this method. Will update on the situation later.

Comment: Now I am getting an error that says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sceneEl is not defined'. How do I define this?

Comment: You may want to read through the docs on using [JavaScript and DOM APIs in A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html).

Comment: I did it. Not exactly what I was looking for but I did it. Thank you dear stranger!